# Bubble Sorting - confused about 2 lines (Beginner)

Tags: bubble-sort

I understood most of the code however I'm just confused about two lines

```
position = position + 1
N = N - 1
```

What do they do in the code and why are they at the end? What alternative ways are there to write these two lines? Is there a more efficient way of writing this code?

```
data = [8,7,12,4,9,6,5]
N = len(data)
swapped = True
while swapped:
    swapped = False
    position = 0

    while (position < N - 1):
        if (data[position] > data[position + 1]):
            hold = data[position]
            data[position] = data[position + 1]
            data[position + 1] = hold
        else:
            swapped = True 
        position = position + 1
    N = N - 1

print(data)
```

Comment: smells like a homework question

Comment: If you are looking for an efficient way, you shouldn't consider bubble sort at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
len(data)=7 // length of array
position=0 //to set at beginning of the array

while(position<N-1) // scans your entire array till end of the array

if(data[position]>data[position+1]) // checks if 8 >7 if true store 8 in temp variable
then loop through to get smallest number at data[position] and 
else 
N=N-1 //get next value of N to meet the condition data[position]>data[position+1]

// prints(sorted array)
```

Equivalent code in C:

```
for(int x=0; x<n; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<n-1; y++)
            {
                if(array[y]>array[y+1])
                {
                    int temp = array[y+1];
                    array[y+1] = array[y];
                    array[y] = temp;

                     }
            }
        }
```

`Notice that this will always loop n times from 0 to n, so the order of this algorithm is O(n^2). This is both the best and worst case scenario because the code contains no way of determining if the array is already in order.`

Well "I think the bubble sort would be the wrong way to go." :)